# Strings are not being displayed in order even after using synchronized()

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I was trying to understand the synchronized function when I observed this issue. First, here is the code -

**SampleThread04.java**

```
public class SampleThread04 extends Thread
{
    public void disp(String s)
    {
        System.out.print("["+s);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

**SampleThread05.java**

```
public class SampleThread05 implements Runnable
{
    SampleThread04 d;
    String s;
    Thread t;
    public SampleThread05(SampleThread04 d1, String s1)
    {
        s = s1;
        t = new Thread(this);
        d = d1;
        t.start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(d){
            d.disp(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**ThreadDemo02.java**

```
public class ThreadDemo02
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SampleThread04 st4 = new SampleThread04();
        new SampleThread05(st4,"one");
        new SampleThread05(st4,"two");
        new SampleThread05(st4,"three");
    }
}
```

I'm getting different outputs as I run the code.

**Output #1:**

```
[one]
[two]
[three]
```

**Output #2:**

```
[three]
[one]
[two]
```

**Output #3:**

```
[three]
[two]
[one]
```

And so on.

Without using synchronized(), I'm getting the following output -

```
[one[two[three]
]
]
```

This is quite understandable but why is it the when I use synchronized(), the strings are sometimes printed out of sequence when without using it I always get the same output. Shouldn't the output be always as follows -

```
[one]
[two]
[three]
```

Please explain how the strings are printed out of sequence. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The synchronized statement only causes the `disp` method to be executed as a whole. Since you are starting a new thread for each string, you can't control which thread gets executed first. Although the threads are being started in order, they don't complete in the same order.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to control the output?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741765/ordering-threads-to-run-in-the-order-they-were-created-started

Comment: that is assuming, that you don't actually care in what order the threads are executed and only want the results to be in order. if you want the method invocations to be executed sequentially, then just don't use threads at all

Comment: @bilesh.g If you want your code to be processed sequentially, don't start additional threads.