# Synchronization Improvement for implementing multiple thread completion in specific order

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait, notify

Problem Statement : Bus can start in any order but will reach their destination in particular order. So bus will wait if its previously expected bus has not yet arrived.

After encountering multiple missed signal and solving them i finally came up with below solution.
My questions : First, How could we modify below code to make it robust from design perspective ? Second, Is there any other synchronization mechanism in JAVA we could use to solve it?

```
public class BusDestination implements Runnable {

private boolean[] busArrivalStatus;
private List<String> busSeq = new ArrayList<>();


private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition prevBusFlag = lock.newCondition();
private CountDownLatch latch;
boolean signalled = false;

public BusDestination(CountDownLatch latch) {
    busSeq.add("B1");
    busSeq.add("B2");
    busSeq.add("B3");
    busSeq.add("B4");
    busSeq.add("B5");

    busArrivalStatus = new boolean[busSeq.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.busSeq.size(); i++) {
        busArrivalStatus[i] = false;
    }
    this.latch = latch;
}


public void run() {

    String busName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

    try{
        lock.lock();
        int busArrrivalSeq = busSeq.indexOf(busName);
        if(busArrrivalSeq==0){
            //first bus arrived
            System.out.println("********    Bus arriaved : "+busName);
            busArrivalStatus[0] = true;
            System.out.println(busName+" will signall");
            signalled = true;
            prevBusFlag.signalAll();
        } else {
            while(!isValidSeq(busName) && !signalled ){
                System.out.println(busName+" going to wait.");
                prevBusFlag.await();
            }
            System.out.println("********    Bus arriaved : "+busName);
            busArrivalStatus[busSeq.indexOf(busName)] = true;
            signalled = true;//getPreviousBusStatus(busName);
            prevBusFlag.signalAll();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Except--"+busName);
    }finally{
        lock.unlock();  
    }
    latch.countDown();
}

private boolean isValidSeq(String busName) {
    int prevIndex = busSeq.indexOf(busName)-1;
    if(!busArrivalStatus[prevIndex]){
        signalled = false;
    }
    return busArrivalStatus[prevIndex];
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(5);

    BusDestination destination = new BusDestination(latch);

    Thread b1 = new Thread(destination);
    Thread b2 = new Thread(destination);
    Thread b3 = new Thread(destination);
    Thread b4 = new Thread(destination);
    Thread b5 = new Thread(destination);

    b1.setName("B1");
    b2.setName("B2");
    b3.setName("B3");
    b4.setName("B4");
    b5.setName("B5");

    b4.start();
    b5.start();
    b3.start();
    b1.start();
    b2.start();

    latch.await();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified by using only the CountDownLatch instance and not require the lock instance.  The issue that you are trying to resolve is the threads n can all execute concurrently but at a certain point thread t has to wait until thread t-1 has reached a certain point. Here is my solution.

```
public class BusDestination {

    private CountDownLatch pre, next;

    public BusDestination(CountDownLatch pre, CountDownLatch next) {
         this.pre = pre;
         this.next = next;
    }

    public void run() {
          // Do work....
          pre.await(); // wait until prior thread{s} are done
          // If required, do more work...
          pre.countDown(); // notify next set of thread{s} that you are done
          // If required, do more work...
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         CountDownLatch first = new CountDownLatch(0); // await will return right away.
         CountDownLatch second = new CountDownLatch(1);
         // Continue creating CountDownLatch....
         CountDownLatch preLast =  new CountDownLatch(1);
         CountDownLatch last = new CountDownLatch(1); // used to wait by the main thread.

         BusDestination firstBus = new BusDestination(first, second);
         // create more destinations
         BusDestination lastBus = new BusDestination(preLast, last);

         // start threads....

        last.await(); // Waits until all of the threads complete

}
```

The nice feature about this solution is that you can create a pipeline in which step n will have to wait on two or more threads to complete in step n - 1 before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, this question could help you: [Ordering threads to run in the order they were created/started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741765/ordering-threads-to-run-in-the-order-they-were-created-started) However, the answers in that question focus on synchronizing after the threads have done their work, which is not exactly the same you want.

Apart from that, is the CountDownLatch not redundant? If you synchronize your thread with signal/await, do you still need to wait for them to finish at the same time?

My idea would to use a queue which defines the order of the buses. A thread peeks the queue (does not remove it), if it is its turn, if removes the element from the queue and signals the other threads. Since concurrent access to the queue is only done in the critical section, a simple `LinkedList` can be used.

The if/else checking for `busArrrivalSeq==0` is quite redundant, they actually do very similar things. Using the queue, it can be simplified to one case.

```
public class BusDestination implements Runnable {


    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition prevBusFlag = lock.newCondition();
    private Queue<String> busSeq;

    public BusDestination(Queue<String> busSeq) {

        this.busSeq = busSeq;
    }


    public void run() {

        String busName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        try {
            lock.lock();

                while (!busSeq.peek().equals(busName) ) {
                    System.out.println(busName + " going to wait.");
                    prevBusFlag.await();
                }
                System.out.println("********    Bus arriaved : " + busName);
                busSeq.remove();

                prevBusFlag.signalAll();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Except--" + busName);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Queue<String> busSeq = new LinkedList<>();
        busSeq.add("B1");
        busSeq.add("B2");
        busSeq.add("B3");
        busSeq.add("B4");
        busSeq.add("B5");

        BusDestination destination = new BusDestination(busSeq);

        Thread b1 = new Thread(destination);
        Thread b2 = new Thread(destination);
        Thread b3 = new Thread(destination);
        Thread b4 = new Thread(destination);
        Thread b5 = new Thread(destination);

        b1.setName("B1");
        b2.setName("B2");
        b3.setName("B3");
        b4.setName("B4");
        b5.setName("B5");

        b4.start();
        b5.start();
        b3.start();
        b1.start();
        b2.start();

    }
}
```