# start thread one by one without using join() in java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, java-threads

am new to thread in java i have a little idea abou thread, lets say i have 10 thread and i start it one by one like this

```
public class BaseRunnable implements Runnable {
    String ThreadNo;
    public  BaseRunnable(String ThreadNo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.ThreadNo=ThreadNo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        {
             System.out.println("Thread no "+ThreadNo+"  Running with index > "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

And in main Methord

```
BaseRunnable runnable=new BaseRunnable("1");//run on main thread
BaseRunnable runnableTwo=new BaseRunnable("2");//run on main thread
BaseRunnable runnable3=new BaseRunnable("3");//run on main thread
BaseRunnable runnable4=new BaseRunnable("4");//run on main thread
BaseRunnable runnabl5=new BaseRunnable("5");//run on main thread
BaseRunnable runnable6=new BaseRunnable("6");//run on main thread
BaseRunnable runnable7=new BaseRunnable("7");//run on main thread
BaseRunnable runnable8=new BaseRunnable("8");//run on main thread


Thread one=new Thread(runnable);
Thread two=new Thread(runnableTwo);
Thread thr3=new Thread(runnable3);
Thread thr4=new Thread(runnable4);
Thread thr5=new Thread(runnabl5);
Thread thr6=new Thread(runnable6);
Thread thr7=new Thread(runnable7);
Thread thr8=new Thread(runnable8);

one.start();
two.start();
thr3.start();
thr4.start();
thr5.start();
thr6.start();
thr7.start();
thr8.start();
```

I know if I use `join()` I can run thready one by one `(one.start(); one.join();)`

I try another way using synchronized that made run one thread one by one but it was not in order, So any Expert help me to active this like Thread one first,Thread 2 etc without `join()`

Please consider this as a question by a beginner, please help

Comment: If there are several tasks to do, but those tasks have to be done in a certain order and the next task cannot start until the prior task is complete, then why are you attempting to use threads at all? Please provide more context around what you're trying to do.

Comment: Am testing and learing thread, recently i got a question on my interview to achive this so i started to figue out how to do achive this. Please conside as learing student. Thank you

Comment: Do you recall the exact interview question?  Is it really the same as your posted question?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741765/ordering-threads-to-run-in-the-order-they-were-created-started) is old but still applies.

Comment: Shouldn't start threads by hand. Take a look an `Executors`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal in this way:

```
        List<BaseRunnable> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            list.add(new BaseRunnable(Integer.toString(i)));
        }

        for (BaseRunnable baseRunnable : list) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(baseRunnable);
            thread.start();
            while (thread.isAlive()) {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
```