# Java - the thread execution order

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to start 10 threads strictly in turn using a semaphore.
That is, after the execution of thread-0, thread-1 should be executed, but not thread-2.

But the problem is that the threads is arrives to the `semaphore.acquire()`-method in out of order, and therefore the execution of the threads is out of order.
How can I solve this problem with semaphore but without using `thread.join()`?

```
public class Main {

    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }

    private void start() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable runnable = () -> {
                try {
                    semaphore.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("In run method " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                semaphore.release();
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
In run method Thread-0
In run method Thread-1
In run method Thread-4
In run method Thread-5
In run method Thread-3
In run method Thread-2
In run method Thread-6
In run method Thread-7
In run method Thread-9
In run method Thread-8
```

Comment: Making threads run sequentially all waiting for a semaphore makes one wonder why even bother with threads. However, if this is just an exercise I think you'd either need separate semaphores or once the semaphore is acquired you check a value to see if you're the "next" thread to run and if not then release and reacquire.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741765/ordering-threads-to-run-in-the-order-they-were-created-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a synchronization object with some sort of concept of ordering.  If you're familiar with US grocery stores, consider the "take a number" device at the deli counter that tells you whose turn it is.

Rough sketch of code:

```
class SyncThing {
   int turn = 0; 
   synchronized void waitForTurn(int me) {
       while (turn != me)
           wait();
   }
   synchronized void nextTurn() {
        turn++;
        notifyAll();
   }
}
```

then declare  `SyncThing syncThing = new SyncThing();`

and run the i'th thread thus:

```
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            syncThing.waitForTurn(i);
            System.out.println("In run method " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            syncThing.nextTurn();
        };
```

This is typed in off the top of my head and is not offered as complete code, but it should show the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void start() {
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int num = i;
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (counter.get() != num) {
            }
            System.out.println("In run method " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            counter.incrementAndGet();
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a spin lock that wastes CPU resources